# load 160MB data, Matlab memory usage jumps 0.5GB to 1.3GB

Tags: matlab

When I `clear all`, the Matlab memory usage drops to 0.5GB.  I then load a `*.mat` file in which the memory requirement is dominated by an object requiring 161MB (from `whos`).  The Matlab memory usage jumps to 1.3GB.  I then run a script that processes the data, creating small data objects/structures in the process. From `whos`, nothing rivals the 161MB object in terms of memory footprint.  However, the Matlab's memory footprint creeps up to 2.2GB during processing, then settles down to 1.6GB when done.  `whos` still reveals the overwhelmingly dominant memory user to be the loaded object.

Why does Matlab use so much memory than the data that it is processing?  It's about 1000 times more.  Is this just to give it the space for intermediate results?

I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit.  My code is pretty simple post-processing script to tally up some of the loaded data.  It invokes no user-defined functions or 3rd party tools.  I understand that readers can't analyze my code to track down the specific causes, but is 1000x memory footprint typical?  What are typical reasons for this?

Comment: No, it's not typical. As currently stated, this question is impossible to answer without details and is certainly not going to be beneficial to other users.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer about how typical it is.  For me, that's useful in itself.  I'll wait a while, and if it is indeed the consensus that this is atypical, I'll remove the question.